# How to construct DTO in Nest.js for @Body

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

I am a beginner in Nest.js and I found it extremely good. I read the official docs and learned about DTOs. When My Body is like this:

```js
{
  "username" : "username",
  "password" : "password"
}
```

then I can simply create `user.dto.ts` like this:

```js
import { IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export class UserDTO {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  username: string;
  @IsNotEmpty()
  password: string;
}
```

Then I use this in my controller like this.

```js
  @Post('login')
  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
  login(@Body() data: UserDTO) {
    return this.userService.login(data);
  }
```

But my question is what if my Body is something like this.

```js
{
  "data": {
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
  }
}
```

then what modifications I need to make in my ```user.dto.ts`` file to make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The answer is: You don't need to modify your `DTO`.

`@Body()` decorator also takes in an optional argument: `@Body(path?: string)`.

The key here is to understand what `@Body()` does. `@Body()` without any argument will return `req.body` object. `@Body('path')` will return `req.body.path`  (or `req.body['path']`. With this knowledge, you can pass `'data'` in `@Body('data')` and it will return `req.body.data` which will be your `DTO`.

```
@Post('login')
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
login(@Body('data') data: UserDTO) {
   // data will be your req.body.data which is your UserDTO
   return this.userService.login(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may create a wrapper class that would carry your dto such as

```
export class Data<T> {

  @ApiModelProperty()
  readonly data: T;

  constructor(data: any = {}) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

and in your controller you will have

```
@Post('login')
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
login(@Body() data: Data<UserDTO>) {
 return this.userService.login(data);
}
```

in your service you will do something like

```
return new Data(this.userDto);
```